# asp.net mvc dropdownlistfor Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create a drop down list using asp.net mvc.

Model:

```
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }

    public AddUser()
    {
        StatusList = new List<SelectListItem>
                         {
                             new SelectListItem{Value = "0",Text = "0"},
                             new SelectListItem{Value = "1",Text = "1"}
                         };
    }
```

View:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Status,new SelectList(Model.StatusList,"Value","Text")) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Status) %>
```

I don't know why but I keep getting this error:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are instantiating StatusList by calling AddUser? Is the correct model being used in the view? Is the view being passed in by the controller?

Comment: Why in the world are you using `new SelectList(Model.StatusList,"Value","Text")` - `StatusList` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - your just creating an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one - its just `Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Status, Model.StatusList)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens when you leave a field of model null or the model is null

Make sure that "Status" isn't null and your return the model in "View" just like this:

```
    //end of an action code
    AddUser model = new AddUser();

    model.Status = "0"; //status can't be null (cause the the exception cited earlier)

    return View(model);  //if you do not pass the model as argument the model will be null in view
}
```

And one more tip for u:
The class `SelectList` implements `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so in view your code may look something like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Status, Model.StatusList) %>
<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Status) %>
```

You don't need instantiate again.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't pass the model to the view. Was still to new to ASP.NET  MVC. Such a simple mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think Travis is right, you've forgot install StatusList, maybe it's null.

Comment: How would you install StatusList?